# Regex to rename multiple files at the same time

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I'm trying to use regex to rename my header files. I could have easily manually changed the files but it's been hours and I've been wrecking my brain trying to figure it out.
I have 3 things I want to do.

1. Remove the prefixed character V.
2. Make camel case to snake case.
3. .h extensions should be .hpp

Examples;

VInstance.h -> instance.hpp

VCommandBuffer.h -> command_buffer.hpp

Comment: Please write the operating system and script language you want to use.

Comment: I'm on mac right now.

Comment: Please read the [regex tag Wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) and add the relevant further details to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Python and `re.sub` to find and replace.

1. `(^V)` will match any `V` at the start of your string, and you can substitute with `` to remove it.
2. To add `_`'s where you want to, `(\B)([A-Z])` will match any uppercase letter in the middle of your string and substituting with `_\2` will match add an underscore before each word (but not the first one) and leave the matching uppercase letter. After that, you can use `.lower()` to make everything lowercase.
3. You can use `(\.h)$` to match anything with a `.h` at the end of your string and then substitute `.hpp`.